# Cumulative array sum in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the slickest, most Ruby-like way of calculating the cumulative sum of an array?

Example:

```
[1,2,3,4].cumulative_sum
```

should return

```
[1,3,6,10]
```

Comment: coming back to this question myself, a mere 5.5 years later!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
class Array
  def cumulative_sum
    sum = 0
    self.map{|x| sum += x}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is one way

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.inject([]) { |x, y| x + [(x.last || 0) + y] }
```

If it is OK that the answer is more than one statement, then this would be cleaner:

```
outp = a.inject([0]) { |x, y| x + [x.last + y] }
outp.shift # To remove the first 0
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 irb> a = (1..10).to_a
 #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
 irb> a.inject([0]) { |(p,*ps),v| [v+p,p,*ps] }.reverse[1..-1]
 #=> [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
```

We could also take a note from Haskell and make a ruby version of [scanr](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:scanr).

```
irb> class Array
   >   def scanr(init)
   >     self.inject([init]) { |ps,v| ps.unshift(yield(ps.first,v)) }.reverse
   >   end
   > end
#=> nil
irb> a.scanr(0) { |p,v| p + v }
=> [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
irb> a.scanr(0) { |p,v| p + v }[1..-1]
=> [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
irb> a.scanr(1) { |p,v| p * v }
=> [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]
```

Comment: +1 for the reference to scanr, that's what an accumulated inject is. Note that you can add scanr to module Enumerable instead of just class Array.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can read about `scanl` — feature you need, but that isn't yet implement in Ruby, as far as I know. Here are examples and sample source code of it: http://billsix.blogspot.com/2008/11/functional-collection-patterns-in-ruby.html

**UPD:**
The above link is dead, so instead I'll say that my Ruby implementation of Wolfram Mathematica's [FoldList[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html) as a part of gem "mll" [here](https://github.com/Nakilon/mll/blob/master/lib/mll.rb#L60) can  be simplified for OP's purpose while being Enumerable:

```
def fold_list array
  start = 0
  Enumerator.new do |e|
    array.each do |i|
      e << start += i
    end
  end
end

irb> fold_list([1,2,3]).to_a
=> [1, 3, 6]
```

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Comment: Yep ( there are a lot of links to it but it's dead. I hope someone find the mirror.

Answer (score 1):

One more approach ( though I prefer **khell**'s)

```
(1..10).inject([]) { |cs, i| cs << i + (cs.last || 0) }
```

I saw the answer posted by **hrnt** after posting my answer. Though two approaches look the same, solution above is more efficient as the same array is used in each inject cycle.

```
a,r = [1, 2, 3, 4],[]
k = a.inject(r) { |x, y| x + [(x.last || 0) + y] }
p r.object_id 
#  35742260
p k.object_id
#  35730450
```

You will notice r and k are different. If you do the same test for the solution above:

```
a,r = [1, 2, 3, 4],[]
k = a.inject(r) { |cs, i| cs << i + (cs.last || 0) }
p r.object_id
# 35717730
p k.object_id
# 35717730
```

The object id for r and k are the same.

Comment: Can be modified to cs.last.to_i as well - not shorter, but maybe more readable ?

Answer (score 1):

unearthing this for one more approach, that **modifies the array in-place**

```
class Array
  def cumulative_sum!
    (1..size-1).each {|i| self[i] += self[i-1] }
    self
  end
end
```

can also be generalized :

```
  def cumulate!( &block )
    (1..size-1).each {|i| self[i] = yield self[i-1], self[i] }
    self
  end

  >> (1..10).to_a.cumulate! {|previous, next| previous * next }
  => [1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
[1,2,3,4].inject([]){ |acc, value| acc << acc.last.to_i + value.to_i }

=> [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Haskell function we want is `scanl`, not `scanr`.

```
class Array
  def scanl(init)
    self.reduce([init]) { |a, e| a.push(yield(a.last, e)) }
  end
end

[1,2,3,4].scanl(0) { |a, b| a + b }[1..-1]
=> [1, 3, 6, 10]
```