# How can I convert this array so that each element represents the cumulative value of the previous elements?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cumulative array sum in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475808/cumulative-array-sum-in-ruby)

I have an array of integers like this

```
[20, 25, 40, 60]
```

How can I turn it into an array with each element representing the cumulative value of the elements before it, including itself?

```
[20, 45, 85, 145]
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.0 & ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475808/cumulative-array-sum-in-ruby

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s = 0
[20, 25, 40, 60].map{|e| s += e}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[20, 25, 40, 60].reduce([]) do |arr, v|
  arr << (arr.last || 0) + v
end
```

Or an *ugly* one liner.

```
[20, 25, 40, 60].reduce([0]){ |a, v| a << a[-1] + v }[1..-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [20, 25, 40, 60]
(array.size - 1).times { |i| array[i + 1] += array[i] }
puts array
# => [20, 45, 85, 145]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Matlab:

```
B = cumsum(A)
```

### Ruby:

```
class Array
  def ruby_cumsum!
    (1..size-1).each {|i| self[i] += self[i-1] }
    self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.each_with_index.map{|x, i| x + (i==0 ? 0 : arr[0..i-1].inject(:+))}

=> [20, 45, 85, 145]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [20, 25, 40, 60]
first = []
sum = 0

arr.each do |e|
  sum += e
  first << sum
end
puts first
```