# Cumulative inverse array sum in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am calculating the sum of array values from each index to end of array. Like so:

```
array = [50, 40, 30,20]
array.map.with_index{|x,i| x = array[i..array.length].reduce(:+) }
=> [140, 90, 50, 20]
```

Is there any cleaner, ruby-like and more efficent way of doing this? Cumulative array sums are already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475808/cumulative-array-sum-in-ruby).

Comment: You can use the same method as mentioned in the question you tagged and reverse the array to get the desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned efficient, I am not following your code of `map.with_index` way: it have time complexity of `O(n^2)`

Inverse cumulative_sum can be done with cumulative_sum and 2 `reverse`:

```
# cumulative sum with O(n) complexity
# from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1475845/327815
class Array
    def cumulative_sum
        sum = 0
        self.map{|x| sum += x}
    end
end

array = [50, 40, 30, 20]
p array.reverse.cumulative_sum.reverse
```

Comment: As Pramod suggested above, it works: ([50,40,30,20].map{|x| x += x}).reverse

Answer (score 8):

I’d define a `scanl` helper that collects the results of a `reduce`:

```
module Enumerable
    def scanl(initial, sym)
        self.reduce([initial]) { |m, n| m << m[-1].send(sym, n) }[1..-1]
    end
end
```

a `scanr` to do that backwards:

```
def scanr(initial, sym)
    self.reverse_each.scanl(initial, sym).reverse
end
```

and that’s it:

```
array.scanr(0, :+)
```

Answer (score 2):

A tricky way to do this:

```
sum = array.inject(a[-1], &:+)
array.map.with_index { |x, i| sum -= a[i-1] }
=> [140, 90, 50, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.each_with_object([array.inject(:+)]){|e, a| a << a.last - e}[0...-1]
# => [140, 90, 50, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.reverse_each.with_object([]) { |n,a| a.unshift(n + a.first.to_i) }
  #=> [140, 90, 50, 20]
```

Starting from the last element of the array and working forward, the sum of each element and the first element of `a` (the array being built, to be returned) is shoved onto the front of `a`. When `a` is empty,

```
a.first.to_i
  #=> [].first.to_i => nil.to_i => 0
```

Alternatively, one could write

```
(a.first || 0)
```

By using [Array#reverse_each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each) only a single pass though `array` is required.